# How to write Pandas DataFrame to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

**Background**

I have a CSV file that is read into a Pandas DataFrame.  I did some transformations on the DataFrame (cleaning and merging columns with other data sources).  I'm left with a DataFrame that I want to write into a new table on Microsoft SQL Server, but Pandas version .13 ([latest](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)) only has 'sqlite', 'mysql', and 'oracle'.

**Question**

How can I go from a DataFrame to a table in MS SQL Server?  Data is not multiple index levels.

I looked through Pandas' 'sql.write_frame' method, but there isn't a 'mssql' flavor.  I attempted the dev build (version .14), but my Windows machine seems to have issues with the MinGW C++ compiler (separate issue).

```
import pandas

#...

#Read CSV file into DataFrame
CallsKO = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filename, \
        sep=';', quotechar='"')

# Select Dataframe and write to SQL, but no mssql support
pandas.io.sql.write_frame(frame=CallsKO, con=cnxn, name='Test', \
        flavor='sqlite')
```

Comment: There are big changes in sql for 0.14 to use SQLAlchemy (though release isn't for a few months, it is already in master), which should allow sqlserver. If you want to give it a try in master and let us know if it works on github...

Comment: I followed the instructions here to build the development version: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/install.html  Even though I reinstalled mingw32 with the C and C++ compilers, I finally got stuck on step: python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32  The error I get is: "undefined reference to '_imp__PyErr_Format collect2: ld returned 1 exit status error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Comment: I recommend posting a github issue about installation...

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I think the issue with building the dev version is with my machine (nothing to do with pandas in particular).  I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684814/python-compile-dev-build-on-windows  I'll keep the comments here just in case someone runs into the same issue.

Comment: If you post an issue it may get more attention, devs are building on windows so I expect they can diagnose... :)

Comment: I posted on the pandas github by adding it to the open issue with building on a windows environment.  Thanks for the encouragement on trying out a dev build @Andy!