# Python Compile Dev Build on Windows

Tags: python, windows, gcc

**Reproduction Steps**

I'm trying to build the development version of Pandas on a Windows 7 machine with Python 2.7.6.  I followed the steps here (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/install.html).

1. I checked that I had the needed dependencies and some of the optional ones as well (Cython=.20, Numpy=1.7.1, Python-DateUtil=1.5, pytz=2013.9)
2. I double checked the dependencies were up to date
3. I cloned the github with: git clone git://github.com/pydata/pandas.git
4. I installed the minGW compiler suite (including C and C++ compilers)
5. The mingw setup is version 4.3.3
6. I made sure that the pydistutils.cfg is in the correct location (C:\Python27\Lib\distutils) and has the following code:

   ```
   [build]
   compiler=mingw32
   ```
7. I attempt to build using: python setup.py build --compiler==mingw32
8. This begins to build for a few seconds, then runs into the below error

**Error**

[image: Error message]

How can I fix this so it builds?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone made the same mistake as me, I realized I'm using a 64-bit Windows 7 with only a 32-bit MinGW compiler.  There's a MinGW 64 bit compiler [here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php) that fixed this issue.